# Read the same attribute from 2 different xml tags

Tags: c#, xml, attributes

I have an xml that contains some data and I want to extract some informations, but I can't figure it out how. I will post an example down below:

```
<ns:Taggg ns:SelectThisValues="3421" xmlns:ns="namespaceURL">3421<ns:AnotherTaggg ns:SomeValue="3421" />
</ns:Taggg>

    <ns:Taggg2 ns:SelectThisValues="3422" xmlns:ns="namespaceURL">3422<ns:AnotherTaggg ns:SomeValue="3421" />
</ns:Taggg2>
```

Based on that, I want to select the values from 'SelectThisValues' attribute, but from both tags , in only one operation.

Namespace is defined as ns in this example.

I don't have very much experience with xml but I know that is possible, is just, I don't know how exactly to do it. Can anybody help me? Any idea is welcomed!

I don't need only the basic idea, I can handle with complexity ideas

Comment: Which class do you use now to load that XML?

Comment: Where is your current attempt? And what do you mean by 'select values in one operation' - what is your expected return value / type?

Comment: @CharlesMager if you hit the down vote button, I hope you'll change your mind. Why do you ask that? Is not obvious? 3421 as string, I just need its value

Comment: I didn't, and it's not obvious. If you select two things at once, what is your return type? It can't be a single string with 3421, as that's not two values.

Comment: I create and XmlNodeList with its sections

Comment: Well that's the point. I need to return '3421' and '3422' in one operation. That means without using 'ns:Taggg' or 'ns:Taggg2' in LINQ

Comment: So I have to search for 'ns:SelectThisValues' in the entire document, without using 'ns:Taggg'..

Comment: OK, I'll try asking another way: what would you *like* the return type to be? A list of strings? A single string containing both values delimited by something?

Comment: Aaaa well that doesn't really matters...list let's say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this pretty trivially with LINQ to XML:

```
XNamespace ns = "namespaceURL";

var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);

var values = doc.Descendants()
    .Attributes(ns + "SelectThisValues")
    .Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: Interesting..but for some reason, I don't get any value

Comment: [It works with your example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dMMmz4). Without a [mcve] that shows it doesn't work, I can't really suggest what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Yeah, is probably my mistake somewhere. Thank you for your support and help. I appreciate!